# Reference for Laplace and Poisson equation (PDE)

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, poissons-equation

It would be helpful if someone could share some exercises, preferably with some solved examples, on solving Laplace and Poisson equation partial differential equations. I have searched various places but I could only find theory everywhere developing proofs by fundamental solution, Green's function, etc.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to do the exercises at the end of Chapter 2 in Evans’ PDE, although these are more concerned with regularity of solutions and such. If it helps, you can read it online for free [here](https://klevas.mif.vu.lt/~algirdas/Evans.pdf).

Comment: @majormaki Thanks for the suggestion